# How do I make a list out of rows from a database using cursor.fetchall with pyodbc?

Tags: python, database, cursor, pyodbc, fetchall

I have a script that works fine on a simple list. It removes some unwanted characters from a list of words, make them match with each other and returns several lists of similar words (with a 0.6 ratio).

But now I need it to work on an Access Database. 
I thought that if I made a for loop on crsr.fetchall() and put all items into a list ("words"), that could work like it previously did. Unfortunatly it doesn't and I really can't figure it out...

Here's my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
import re 
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

[x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith('Microsoft Access Driver')]

# Connection to accdb

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\\Users\\alice\\Desktop\\lexique3.accdb;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

# Put all words into a list 

crsr.execute('SELECT unites_lexicales FROM Mot;')
result1 = crsr.fetchall()
words = []
for item in result1 :
    words.append[item]
print(words)
```

At this point, I got an error :

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried to iterate with range :

```
crsr.execute('SELECT unites_lexicales FROM Mot;')
result = crsr.fetchall()
words = []
for i in range(0, len(result)) :
    words.append(result[i])
print(words)
```

But I got a list of items that looks like this and it's not satisfying at all :

```
[('anbaglé', ), ('anfoutan', ), ('òrdinè', ), ('alakous', ), ('ayen', ), ('anmè', ), ('antòtiyé', ),...]
```

Here's the rest of the code that worked perfectly on a simple list :

```
radicals = [] 
motifp = "^(re|em|dés)" 
motifs = "(iste|ment|er|ant|able)$" 

for word in words : 
    word = re.sub(motifp, '', word) 
    word = re.sub(motifs, '', word) 
    radicals.append(word) 
print(radicals) 

ratio = 0.6
n = len(radicals)
result = []
used_js = []

for i in range(n):
    if i in used_js:
        continue
    matches = [words[i]]
    js = (x for x in range(n) if x != i and x not in used_js)
    for j in js:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, radicals[i], radicals[j]).ratio() >= ratio : 
            matches.append(words[j])
            used_js.append(j)
    result.append(matches)
print(result)
```

Here is the result I got earlier by testing it on a simple list :

```
[['flore', 'fleur', 'fleuriste'], ['remaniement', 'remanier', 'manier', 'maniable'], ['désaimer', 'aimant', 'aimer'], ['désemmêler', 'emmêler', 'mêler']]
```

I must have gotten the whole cursor section wrong, I really don't understand how that works... Thanks for your help !

Comment: In your first code snippet you are using words.append[item]. You should use words.append(item).  append is a method.

Comment: Okay thanks, but is there any way I can put items from this column into a list ?

Comment: The rows returned from fetchall() behave like tuples but you can access columns by name as well.  Inside of your loop try **words.append(item['unites_lexicales'])** or **words.append(item[0])** .  There are some good examples [here via the documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#selecting-some-data).

Comment: Thanks @Kyle but it doesn't work... I edited my post so you can show the result, it's the same as when I'm trying with range.

Answer (score 4):

You can index into each row with a index. This row only has one column so you can use 0.  You can also index into it via the name.

```
# ...
crsr.execute('SELECT unites_lexicales FROM Mot;')
result = crsr.fetchall()
words = []
for row in result:
    # words.append(row['unites_lexicales'])
    words.append(row[0])
print(words)
# ...
```

You could also use a list comprehension to get that first column.

```
# ...
crsr.execute('SELECT unites_lexicales FROM Mot;')
result = crsr.fetchall()
# words = [row['unites_lexicales'] for row in result]
words = [row[0] for row in result]
print(words)
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works when I try separately : I do have my words list, I also have my radicals list, but when I try everything altogether I don't get anything. No error message, no words, nothing but a dark screen... any clue ?

Comment: When I try with ['unites_lexicales'] I get the following error : TypeError: row indices must be integers, not str

Comment: What part of your code is breaking? This seems to be something different than your original question.  Are you getting data back from the sql query?

Comment: After testing each part of the code separately : I'm getting the data, I have my words list and my radicals list. I think it has to do with the last part, but that's really weird since it still works fine with a simple list !

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to stumble on this post & thought I'd complete it. I had the same question. Correct syntax is Row.ColumnName not row['ColumnName'] when using pyodbc. Quirky but it works